# How to run my Python TestCase using Jenkins "Selenium" Plugin?

Tags: python, selenium, jenkins, headless

How to Integrate jenkins with Selenium-webdriver.  I am using Python language for Selenium TestCases. I have tried 'pyvirtualdisplay' Python module to hide the display on Jenkins CLI. Currently I have used ant build scripts to execute the Python Test Suit.

I want to use Jenkins "Selenium" plugin to integrate my Python Testcases. But "Selenium" plugin allows only "HTMLSuite" files.

How to run my Python TestCase using Jenkins "Selenium" Plugin?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried downloading the Selenium Plugin (the one that says Grid on the description) and what it does is creates a Selenium Server on Jenkins. Then, if you read the specifications of the plugin (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Selenium+Plugin) you will see that you need to indicate your script to target Jenkin's Selenium Server that is running.

I get to run my test outside Jenkins but does not start a broswer (is headless) and is not doing some of the visual commands (as easy as take as screenshoot).

Then I saw this video that helps to build a task with a Selenium testcase:

http://www.dailymotion.com/video/xkw0zb_jenkins-running-a-selenium-job_tech

1. Hudson is an older version of Jenkins
2. He creates a build.xml that basically does everything.

I am still investigating on how to create that build.xml file

Hope all this helps you somehow.

Best of lucks,